# Can IntelliJ auto complete and include simple generics?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, intellisense

I have recently switched back to IntelliJ from Eclipse and one thing I am struggling with is the auto complete, especially when declaring Collections. **This is not a question about which IDE is better its just a question on how to perform a task if that task is possible **

In IntelliJ I type

```
List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayL  (then key stroke **Alt Ctrl Space**)
```

I get

```
List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList
```

Which saves me typing three letters, not a great saving I am sure you will agree

If I use Eclipse and use the key stroke Ctrl Space on

```
List<String> listOfNames = new Ar
```

I get this result including the generics

```
List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<String>()
```

I am sure I am missing something like a keystroke I can't find or a plugin I need to add.

Thanks

Comment: Man, why was this question downvoted?  I came here looking for an answer to this exact question, and came away happy to find a solution. +1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

type

```
List<String> listOfNames = new //be aware of the space after new
```

and press crtl+shift+spacebar, magic happens!

Comment: Thanks, that was easy, I was using ctrl alt space instead of ctrl shift space (this is getting tricky switching between mac and pc)